# JSON getting value

Tags: json

I'm currently working with the Steam API but not everything is working out the way it should be.

The (first part of the) JSON file looks like this:

```
{
"playerstats": {
    "steamID": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "total_kills",
            "value": 4910
        },
        {
            "name": "total_deaths",
            "value": 3691
        },
        {
            "name": "total_time_played",
            "value": 280969
        },
```

I want to access the value of total kills by using the name; this is because the order of the stats is different for each player which means I can't use [0] or [1] for example.

I already have the decoding part:

```
$csgo = json_decode(file_get_contents($apiurl_csgo), true);
```

But now I need to access the total kills value by checking if the name of the 'thingy' (no idea what it's called) is equal to "total_kills".

Previously I used $cs_kills = $csgo["playerstats"]["stats"][0]["value"];
but I found out that doesn't work always because the order of stats can be different.

I hope you guys understand my questions and can help me!

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, I'm from Holland.

Lars

Comment: What language is this?  PHP?  You need to tag your question with the programming language that you're using.

Comment: @jwodder Sorry I'm new to this website, I'll do it the next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get that stat you want:

```
$total_kills = 0;
foreach($csgo["playerstats"]["stats"] as $stat) {
   if($stat['name'] == 'total_kills') {
     $total_kills = $stat['value'];
     break;
   }
}
```

Array reduce (for fun)

```
$total_kills = array_reduce($csgo['playerstats']['stats'],function($carry,$stat) {
  return $carry ? $carry : ($stat['name'] == 'total_kills' ? $stat['value'] : $carry);
},0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use foreach:

```
<?
$json_string='{"playerstats":{"steamID": "XXXXXXXXXXXX","gameName":"ValveTestApp260","stats":[{"name":"total_kills","value":4910},{"name":"total_deaths","value": 3691},{"name": "total_time_played", "value": 280969}]}}';
$obj=json_decode($json_string);
foreach ($obj->playerstats->stats as &$value) {
    if($value->name == 'total_kills'){
        echo $value->value;
        // Do somethig with value
    }
}
?>
```